# SQL statement select columns with specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help making an sql statement; I don't really know how to aproach the situation. I have two tables, Departments and Employees
from which I want to select the *Dpt_num* and the *Dpt_name* of the departments that have at least one employee and that all their employees are from Barcelona

**Case 1**

```
== Departments =======
| Dpt_num | Dpt_name |
|    1    |    A     |
|    2    |    B     |

== Employees ===================
| E_num | Dpt_num |  City      |
|  1    |   1     | Barcelona  |
|  2    |   1     | Barcelona  |
```

The result in this case should be

```
 Dpt_num Dpt_name
 ------------------
    1       A
```

**Case 2**

```
== Departments =======
| Dpt_num | Dpt_name |
|    1    |    A     |
|    2    |    B     |

== Employees ==================
| E_num | Dpt_num | City      |
|   1   |    1    | Barcelona |
|   2   |    1    | Madrid    |
```

The result in this case should be empty.

I tried this for example but it seems very inefficient and it does not work in all the cases

```
select
    num_dpt, nom_dpt
from
    departements
where
    1 = (select count(distinct e.ciutat_empl)
         from empleats e
         where e.num_dpt = num_dpt)
    and not exists (select * from empleats e
                    where e.ciutat_empl != 'BARCELONA' and e.num_dpt = num_dpt);
```

I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: . . Have you tried anything?  I can think of several different approaches to answering this question.

Comment: Yes but they did not work, I will post a failing example

Comment: Try using HAVING COUNT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go down the path of doing the filtering in the `where` clause.  Then, use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select d.num_dpt, d.nom_dpt 
from departaments d
where exists (select 1
              from empleats e
              where e.num_dpt = d.num_dpt and e.ciutat_empl = 'BARCELONA' 
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from empleats e
                  where e.num_dpt = d.num_dpt and e.ciutat_empl <> 'BARCELONA' 
             );
```

The first condition checks that at least one employee is from Barcelona.  The second checks that no employees are from any other city.

One major problem in your version is your correlation clause:

```
e.num_dpt = num_dpt
```

You think this is doing:

```
e.num_dpt = departaments.num_dpt
```

But it is really doing:

```
e.num_dpt = e.num_dpt
```

*Always* qualify your column names.  This is especially important when you have more than one table reference in the query.

Comment: How is it doing `e.num_dpt = d.num_dpt` if there's no specified `d`? I think you meant `e.num_dpt = e.num_dpt`.

Comment: @KamilG. . . . Good catch.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, group by the department and check if the count of employees in Barcelona is equal to the count of all employess of the department.

```
SELECT d.dpt_num,
       d.dpt_name
       FROM departments d
            INNER JOIN employees e
                       ON e.dpt_num = d.dpt_num
       GROUP BY d.dpt_num,
                d.dpt_name
       HAVING count(CASE
                      WHEN e.city = 'Barcelona' THEN
                        1
                    END) = count(*);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
select d.dpt_num, d.dpt_name
from departments d
inner join employees e on
  d.dpt_num = e.dpt_num
group by d.dpt_num, d.dpt_name
having count(*) = sum(case when e.city = 'Barcelona' then 1 else 0 end)
```

- `INNER JOIN` makes sure there's at least 1 employee
- `HAVING count(*) = sum(case when e.city = 'Barcelona' then 1 else 0 end)` makes sure that all employees are from Barcelona

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you compare `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(some condition)` for such problems:

```
SELECT *
FROM Departments
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   Employees
    WHERE  Employees.Dpt_num = Departments.Dpt_num
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 -- it is possible to get a 0 if where did not match
    AND    COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN Employees.City = 'Barcelona' THEN 1 END)
)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2c5923a133576e1373e82c5ea2ae36e8)

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3646db92207fdf510c907f1243830e58)

```
SELECT dpt_num, dpt_name
FROM (
    SELECT d.dpt_num, d.dpt_name, array_agg(city) as cities
    FROM dept d
    JOIN empl e
    ON d.dpt_num = e.dpt_num
    GROUP BY d.dpt_num, d.dpt_name
) s
WHERE 'Barcelona' = ALL(cities)
```

Aggregate the cities and then you can filter with the `ALL` operator which checks if all array elements fit the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Pl try query below

```
select a.dpt_number,a.dpt_name from yy_department a 
where exists (select 'x' from yy_employees y where y.dpt_number = a.dpt_number and y.city = 'Barcelona') 
and not exists (select 'x' from yy_employees y where y.dpt_number = a.dpt_number and nvl(y.city,'x') <> nvl('Barcelona','y'))
```